# pushing new array into a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to push a new array into a global array here:

```
var history = [ ];

function addHistory(array)
{
history.push(array);
console.log(history)//to check what is the value of array
}

var test1 = [0,0,0,0,0];
var test2 = [1,1,1,1,1];
addHistory(test1);
addHistory(test2);
```

After doing like this, the array should be:

```
[ [0,0,0,0,0] , [1,1,1,1,1] ]
```

But instead it prints

```
[ [1,1,1,1,1] , [1,1,1,1,1] ]
```

So basically it replaces all old arrays in array "history", instead of pushing it at the end.

What can be wrong here?
Thanks a lot

EDIT:
Sorry, forgot to mention that my actual variable is not called history (I called it that way just that you can imagine what I want). It is called "**rollHist**"

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, it's the same with every name.. Maybe there is another way of inserting new array into an array?

Answer (score 2):

`history` is a protected term in javascript. Changing it to this will fix it:

```
var myHistory = [];

function addHistory(array)
{
myHistory.push(array);
console.log(myHistory)//to check what is the value of array
}

var test1 = [0,0,0,0,0];
var test2 = [1,1,1,1,1];
addHistory(test1);
addHistory(test2);
```

You can read more about the various protected words [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Comment: It's not a bug. `history` is indeed a reserved word, that's all.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that as a bug in his code! I've removed that word haha