# Push array into multidimension array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm facing weird situation while trying to perform simple operation of pushing array into multidimension array. Here is a code:

```
var Atest = Array();
var Btest = ([0, 0, 0, 0]);

Btest[0] = 1;
Btest[1] = 2
Btest[2] = 3;
Btest[3] = 4;
Atest.push([Btest]);

Btest[0] = 11;
Btest[1] = 12;
Btest[2] = 13;
Btest[3] = 14;
Atest.push([Btest]);

document.write("<br>" + Atest);
```

And I'm expecting to get the following output:

```
1,2,3,4,11,12,13,14
```

However, I'm getting unexpected output:

```
11,12,13,14,11,12,13,14
```

What I'm missing?

*(PS: Found similar **unanswered** question asked ~5 years ago: [pushing new array into a 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684457/pushing-new-array-into-a-2d-array))*

Comment: The values of `Btest` are being modified twice.

Comment: you should use `atest.concat(btest)`;

Comment: This is because arrays are mutable, so you need to deep clone while pushing to a new array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push `Btest` into `Atest` you push a *pointer* to the `Btest` array.

You need to copy the underlying values contained inside of `Btest`.

Example using the `spread operator` which will create a copy of the data :

```js
const Atest = Array();
const Btest = ([0, 0, 0, 0]);

Btest[0] = 1;
Btest[1] = 2
Btest[2] = 3;
Btest[3] = 4;
Atest.push([...Btest]);

Btest[0] = 11;
Btest[1] = 12;
Btest[2] = 13;
Btest[3] = 14;
Atest.push([...Btest]);

document.write(`<br>${Atest}`);
```

Comment: [I don't think JS uses pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382427/are-there-pointers-in-javascript) (although I think this is an engine implementation detail)

Comment: no worries. I personally don't think it matters much, but I hope it helps